# Некорректное отображение изображений в хроме на Андроид

Tags: android, google-chrome

у меня проблема.
В моей мобильной версии хрома творится какая-то дребедень. Дело в том, что часть изображений отображается некорректно (примеры на фото).
[image: полу прозрачная кнопка ютуба]
*Прозрачная кнопка ютуба*

[image: формула потеряла букву]

*бува скрылась за шторкой*

[image: галочка поменяла цвет]

*галочка поменяла цвет*

Я заметил что не отображаются именно svg формат. Png jpg web и так далее работают идеально

Буду сильно рад, если поможете!

UPD: пока проверял вопрос ещё такое заметил:
[image: лупа и кубок]

Comment: Пишите в Гугл. Мы ничем не поможем

Comment: Думаю переустановить, если не получится придётся писать в поддержку